# Modelling blogs and ratings in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a blogs collection that contains title, body and agrregate rating that the users have given to them. Another collection 'Ratings' whose schema has reference to the blog, user who rated(if at all he rates them) it in the form of their ObjectIds and the rating they have given ie., +1 or -1.

When a particular user browses through blogs in the 'latest first' order (say 40 of them per page. Call them an array of `blogs[0]` to `blogs[39]`) I have to retrieve the rating documents related to this particular user and those 40 blogs if at all the user rated them and notify him of what ratings he has given those blogs.

I tried to extract all rating documents of a particular user in which blog reference objectIds lie between `blogs[0]._id` and `blogs[39]._id` which returns empty list in my case. May be objectIds cant be compared using `$lt` and `$gt` queries. In that case how should I go about it? Should I redesign my schemas to fit to this scenario?

I am using mongoosejs driver for this case. Here are the relevant parts of the code which differ a bit in execution but youu get the idea.

Schemas:

```
Client= new mongoose.Schema({
    ip:String
})

Rates = new mongoose.Schema({
    client:ObjectId,
    newsid:ObjectId,
    rate:Number
})

News = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  body: String,
  likes:{type:Number,default:0},
  dislikes:{type:Number,default:0},
  created:Date,
  // tag:String,
  client:ObjectId,
  tag:String,
  ff:{type:Number,default:20}
});
```

models:

```
var newsm=mongoose.model('News', News);
var clientm=mongoose.model('Client', Client);
var ratesm=mongoose.model('Rates', Rates);
```

Logic:

```
newsm.find({tag:tag[req.params.tag_id]},[],{ sort:{created:-1},limit: buffer+1 },function(err,news){

ratesm.find({client:client._id,newsid:{$lte:news[0]._id,$gte:news.slice(-1)[0]._id}},function(err,ratings){
 })
})
```

Edit:
While implementing the below said schema, I had to do this query in mongoose.js

```
> db.blogposts.findOne()
{ title : "My First Post", author: "Jane",
  comments : [{ by: "Abe", text: "First" },
              { by : "Ada", text : "Good post" } ]
}
> db.blogposts.find( { "comments.by" : "Ada" } )
```

How do I do this query in mongoose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good practice with MongoDB (and other non-relational data stores) is to model your data so it is easy to use/query in your application. In your case, you might consider denormalizing the structure a bit and store the rating right in the blog collection, so a blog might look something like this:

```
{
  title: "My New Post",
  body: "Here's my new post. It is great. ...",
  likes: 20,
  dislikes: 5,
  ...
  rates: [
    { client_id: (id of client), rate: 5 },
    { client_id: (id of another client), rate: 3 },
    { client_id: (id of a third client), rate: 10 }
  ]
}
```

The idea being that the objects in the `rates` array contains all the data you'll need to display the blog entry, complete with ratings, right in the single document. If you also need to query the rates in another way (e.g. find all the ratings made by user X), and the site is read-heavy, you may consider *also* storing the data in a `Rates` collection as you're doing now. Sure, the data is in two places, and it's harder to update, but it may be an overall win after you analyze your app and how it accesses your data.

Note that you can apply indexes deep into a document's structure, so for example you can index `News.rates.client_id`, and then you can quickly find any documents in the `News` collection that a particular user has rated.

Comment: ok. I changed my schemas as you said but I still have problem as to how I get the ratings given by user for a given blog set. Can you please also help me regarding the specific api? @Brandon

Comment: What if there are millions of rates for an item? Is it a problem for that kind of schema?

Comment: Embedding rates inside the document isn't good. What if you have millions of rates as @Burak mentioned and what if someone need to change his rating? too complex